# Get InvalidOperatorException was unhandled upon compiling

Tags: vb.net

Everything was compiling just fine until validation for text fields was implemented.

Why won't it compile?

> An error occurred creating the form.
>   See Exception.InnerException for
>   details. The error is: External
>   component has thrown an exception.

The source:

```
Public Class frmAddStudent
    Dim aryData(6) As String
    Public Shared newStudentRecord As String

    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAddStudent_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddStudent.Click
        'place all the student field data into the array of elements
        aryData(0) = txtFirstName.Text
        aryData(1) = txtLastName.Text
        aryData(2) = txtMajor.Text
        aryData(3) = txtPhone.Text
        aryData(4) = txtEmail.Text
        aryData(5) = txtGPA.Text

        'join the array elements and place the result into a string variable
        newStudentRecord = Join(aryData, " ")

        'create a link between the form and the file with streamwriter and write to the text file
        If System.IO.File.Exists(frmMain.FILE_NAME) = True Then
            Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(frmMain.FILE_NAME, True)
            objWriter.WriteLine(newStudentRecord)
            objWriter.Close()
        End If
        Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtFirstName_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles txtFirstName.Validating
        If txtFirstName.Text.Contains(" ") Or txtFirstName.Text.Length = 0 Or Not System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtFirstName.Text, "[a-z|A-Z]+$") Then
            ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtFirstName, "First Name can't contain spaces or be of zero length and must consist of only letters")
            e.Cancel = True
        Else
            ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtFirstName, "")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmAddStudent_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ErrorProvider1.BlinkStyle = ErrorBlinkStyle.NeverBlink
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtLastName_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles txtLastName.Validating
        If txtLastName.Text.Contains(" ") Or txtLastName.Text.Length = 0 Or Not System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtLastName.Text, "[a-z|A-Z]+$") Then
            ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtLastName, "Last Name can't contain spaces or be of zero length and must consist of only letters")
            e.Cancel = True
        Else
            ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtLastName, "")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtMajor_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles txtMajor.Validating
        If txtMajor.Text.Length > 0 Then
            If Not System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(Strings.Left(txtMajor.Text, 1), "[a-z|A-Z]+$") Then
                ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtMajor, "Major course code is incorrect")
            Else
                ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtMajor, "")
            End If
        Else
            ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtMajor, "Major cant' be zero length")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**EDIT: Here's also a link to a PrtSc of the problem:** http://img88.imageshack.us/i/imageqc.gif/

Comment: It looks like your ErrorProvider1 is throwing an exception.  Can you please edit the question telling us more information on the error and on what line it occurs?

Comment: I've eited to post to include a link to a print screen image of the issue(right at the most bottom of the thread, under all of the source). As for information on the error and what line it occurs on... it doesn't really say which line it is.

Comment: This is a bad one.  Reboot your machine.

Comment: Any suggestions? This has been bothering me for quiet a while. Feeling very drowsy.